# FunctionDomain ouput conflict with Limit output

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, evaluation

I was just trying to find out the available domain for a function using the following :

```
FunctionDomain[-((I*a*(-1 + E^(2*I*a*Pi)))/(-1 + a^2)), a, Complexes]
```

& this unexpectedly returned : `-1 + a^2 != 0` whereas I had previously checked :

```
Limit[-((I*a*(-1 + E^(2*I*a*Pi)))/(-1 + a^2)), a -> 1]
```

which returned as expected a `Pi`.

Can someone please explain why `FunctionDomain` failed? How can one trust it's output when it didn't calculate the limits here? I suspect that I am doing something incorrectly.

Furthermore, I also didn't understand the output of the following :

```
FunctionDomain[-((I*a*(-1 + E^(2*I*a*Pi)))/(-1 + a^2)), a, Reals] (* False *)
```

Also, how would someone extract the information about the domain for non-zero range (those values of `a` where my expression is not zero) in this case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

expr = -((I*a*(-1 + E^(2*I*a*Pi)))/(-1 + a^2));

Limit[expr, a -> #] & /@ {-1, 1}

(* {π, π} *)

FunctionDomain[expr, a, Complexes]

(* -1 + a^2 != 0 *)
```

This indicates that the function is undefined for `a = 1` or `a = -1`. The fact that the limits exist does not indicate that the function is defined for these values.

This is similar to `Sin[x]/x` which is undefined for `x = 0` but the limit as `x -> 0` is `1`. In this case, `Sinc[x]` is defined to include the limiting case in the function definition.

```
FunctionDomain[expr, a, Reals]

(* False *)
```

This indicates that there are no real values of `a` for which `expr` is real.

Comment: Thank you for such a nice explanation. Could you say one more thing here? What if I have to use such an expression in an integral or something? Will I have to be careful about this? One could very well have expressions which are not feasible to be examined by hand. What to do in that case?

Comment: Your comment is too general for me to understand. If you have a **specific** question, post it as a new question.